# Adjust sizes and thickness independently via update in R package lattice

Tags: r, lattice

The data to be plotted comes from using the R package `mirt`. In particular, I use the `itemplot` function. For an accessible plot without color, I use the following suggestion listed in the [mirt documentation [p. 85]](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mirt/mirt.pdf)

```
# change colour theme of plots
bwtheme <- standard.theme("pdf", color=FALSE)
plot(pmod, type='trace', par.settings=bwtheme)
itemplot(pmod, 1, type = 'trace', par.settings=bwtheme)
```

In addition to the color changes, the following changes should be made. These are the increase in :

1. thickness of curves,
2. font size of labels,
3. font size of axis,
4. thickness of marks on the labels,
5. all parts of legend in general.

In the same documentation, the `update` function of the package `lattice` is suggested for further changes:

```
# additional modifications can be made via update().
# See ?update.trellis for further documentation
```

I have successfully addressed the thickness of curves (aspect 1) directly in `itemplot`:

```
plt <- itemplot(pmod, 1
                , par.settings=bwtheme
                , lwd = 3 # adjust line thickness
               )
```

I have also successfully tackled aspects 3 and 4 in `update`:

```
update(plt
         , scales = list(
             cex = 2.5 # make labels on x-axis and y-axis bigger
             , lwd = 4 # line ticking along the axis, greater number -> thicker 
         )
      )
```

All previous lines of code generate the following image, which you can find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQa4v.png) .

I made several unsuccessful attempts to use `cex` and variants of it for aspect 2, but failed. The same is true for aspect 5. I was able to increase the line marker line width (thanks to [R lattice: How to adjust the legend marker line width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498677/r-lattice-how-to-adjust-the-legend-marker-line-width)). However, this does not make the labels themselves in the legend any larger. Is there a way to increase the size of the legend in general?

I would be very happy if someone could help me with the implementation of points 2 and 5.